# My Jar not creating a log file whereas normal application does

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, logback

I developed an application which is using logback with slf4j. Here is my logback.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
   <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/tmp/alerttest.log</file>
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>


  <!-- Strictly speaking, the level attribute is not necessary since -->
  <!-- the level of the root level is set to DEBUG by default.       -->
  <root level="DEBUG">          
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />

  </root>  

</configuration>
```

So it is writing logs to `/tmp/alerttest.log` . When I run it in eclipse, it runs and creates a log file and write logs to it.  But Now I created an executable Jar file of the project named `alerttesting.jar.` When I run it using `java -jar alerttesting.jar` , it runs successfully but doesn't create the file in `/tmp/`. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the program prints to stdout/stderr? Are there error messages from the logging framework? Where did you put the `logback.xml` file? Can you upload the JAR?

Comment: No. There are no error messages. The program prints the normal logs of the application to stdout.  logback.xml is in src/main/resources. I think it is able to pick up logback.xml because that is why it is able to  show the logs on stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

logback.xml should be in your classpath or use "-Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml"

Other than that, make sure that you are packaging it via maven and not eclipse.

Comment: logback.xml is in the class path. Also, it is able to take logback.xml as it is showing the logs on stdout.

Comment: By default logback write to stdout. Where is the logback.xml ?

Comment: But shouldn't logback.xml be included in the jar itself? My logback.xml is in project's src/main/resources. It is inside class path only right?

Comment: Yes, it should work. Can you check if logback.xml is in your .jar ?

Comment: How you package your jar file ? with maven in "one-jar-with-all-dependencies" ?

Comment: No. I used the export -> Create runnable jar file -->  that way!

Comment: Try with maven package because i don't think that eclipse do right is job when using maven

Comment: But in the jar there are all dependencies.

Comment: Yes but if you're using Maven, you should package with Maven not eclipse. Please try this

Comment: I have updated your answer with the comment. Thanks for the help, it worked.